# hive sql adding record count as column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have records similar to the below

```
fruit      day
apple      1/1/1990   
apple      1/2/1990
apple      1/3/1990
plum       1/1/1990
orange     1/1/1990
orange     1/2/1990
orange     1/3/1990
```

I want to keep a running total for items for each day assuming item will increase by 1 every day. For example

```
fruit      day            count
apple      1/1/1990       1
apple      1/2/1990       2
apple      1/3/1990       3
plum       1/1/1990       1
orange     1/1/1990       1
orange     1/2/1990       2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use windowed `COUNT`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY fruit ORDER BY day)
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=125f629ac3398d0ec7a4db42d087b9fd)**

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala COUNT could be windowed with ORDER BY. Please check provided demo

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `subquery`:

```
select *,
       (select count(*) from table where fruit  = t.fruit and day <= t.day) count
from table t;
```